# JaCoCo test coverage: How to exclude a class inside jar from report?

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

In JBoss AS 7 integration testsuite, we use JaCoCo for code coverage.
I have the execution data already.
Now when generating the report, I get "Can't add different class with same name: ..."
So I have to exclude some jars.

```
<exclude name="org/jboss/osgi/framework/main/jbosgi-resolver-metadata-1.0.10.jar"/>
```

The problem is that only one class is duplicated (`org/jboss/osgi/metadata/internal/AbstractPackageAttribute`).
I only want that particular class excluded, not whole jar.

I've tried:

```
 <exclude name="org/jboss/osgi/framework/main/**/AbstractPackageAttribute*"/>
```

But that doesn't work.
Is there some special syntax, like `.../foo.jar!**/ClassName.class`?

Comment: Have you tried <exclude name="org/jboss/osgi/metadata/internal/AbstractPackageAttribute" /> ? or <exclude>org/jboss/osgi/metadata/internal/AbstractPackageAttribute</exclude>

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038840/418599 for my solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the zipfileset tag:

```xml
<sourcefiles>
  <zipfileset>
    <fileset dir="foo.jar">
      <exclude name="org/jboss/osgi/framework/main/**/AbstractPackageAttribute*.*"/>
    </fileset>
  </zipfileset>
</sourcefiles>
```

Comment: where? inside of the jacoco-maven-plugin <excludes>?

Comment: Could you please add more information to this answer and explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673356/jacoco-cant-add-different-class-with-same-name-org-hamcrest-basedescription/67521056#67521056) will help you.