# jacoco : Cannot exclude classes

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a maven project and I want to use `jacoco` for code coverage. Here is the relevant section of my pom

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-my-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-my-test</id>
                        <phase>post-my-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So I am able to run my tests just fine and also build the project just fine. Then I run

```
mvn clean verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent
```

I keep getting errors like

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:
report (post-my-test) on project my-project: 
An error has occurred in JaCoCo Test report generation. 
Error while creating report: 
Error while analyzing class /path/tp/my/project/target/classes/META-INF/
bundled-dependencies/some-third-party-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar@org/slf4j/event/
EventConstants.class. Can't add different class with same name: 
org/slf4j/event/EventConstants -> [Help 1]
```

`some-third-party-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar` is an external dependency that I have. This is an uber/shaded jar. So I thought that `some-third-party-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar` must also have `org.slf4j`, hence the conflict. So I made a change to the pom as

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/org/slf4j/event/EventConstants.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but I still get the same error. How can I make sure that jacoco ignores all duplicate dependencies? I also tried

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>some.third.party</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-third-party</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

but that did not work. Is it possible to have exclusions from shaded/uber jars?

Moreover, why does jacoco care? Is there any way to fix or ignore these errors? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Excluding the dependency won't work if it's in the actual uber JAR. Did you try the solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133116/jacoco-test-coverage-how-to-exclude-a-class-inside-jar-from-report ?

Comment: thanks, I had not looked at that post. but where do i put `<sourcefiles>
  <zipfileset>
    <fileset dir="foo.jar">
      <exclude name="org/jboss/osgi/framework/main/**/AbstractPackageAttribute*.*"/>
    </fileset>
  </zipfileset>
</sourcefiles>` ?

Comment: i mean under which tag?

Comment: Never mind, that only exists in the ant version and you use the actual Maven plugin. Looking at the error messages I'm not quite sure how it'll treat your path as it contains an @ and path within the JAR. I'd try a more general exclusion like `**/event/EventConstants*` or similar option.

Comment: thanks, i tried `**/event/EventConstants*` but it did not work

Comment: See if you find any hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673356/jacoco-cant-add-different-class-with-same-name-org-hamcrest-basedescription

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Property `excludes` of `report` goal specifies which files should be excluded from analysis during generation of report. In case of `/path/tp/my/project/target/classes/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/some-third-party-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar@org/slf4j/event/EventConstants.class` file is `/path/tp/my/project/target/classes/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/some-third-party-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar` , and the rest is about class in JAR file.

Therefore as one of examples of correct configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
  </excludes>
</configuration>
```

As a proof having `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

`src/main/java/Example.java`

```
public class Example {
}
```

and `src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
public class ExampleTest {
  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
  }
}
```

Execution of

```
mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent package
mkdir target/classes/META-INF/
cp ~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.4.2/slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar target/classes
cp ~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar target/classes/META-INF
mvn jacoco:report
```

will fail with message

```
Error while analyzing /private/tmp/j/target/classes/slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar@org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMarker.class. Can't add different class with same name: org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMarker
```

while same execution with `pom.xml` containing exclusion of `META-INF/**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

will succeed.

As a side note: [semantic of property `excludes` of `prepare-agent` goal is different](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/34#issuecomment-10205525) - it specifies class names (regardless of their on-disk location) that should be excluded from instrumentation during execution of tests.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the duplication issue by adding `<phase>prepare-package</phase>` to the report execution task:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-agent</id>
      <goals>
      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>report</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
      <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you also add some description of the root cause in order to understand why is this solving it?

Answer (score 0):

/** is for traversing into underlying directories and different than * which is a character wild card for names. Avoiding ** can result in undesirable effect.

Comment: It seems that this not answer the original question but it's a generic advice.